# How old are the members of La Familia Madrigal at the time of the movie?

Tags: disney, encanto

I find it hard to judge the age of each family member of La Familia Madrigal from the Disney movie "Encanto". For example, if I understand this correctly, Bruno, who looks like in his 30s, has to be around 50 years old.

What is the age of each member of La Familia Madrigal at the time when the movie takes place?

Comment: I'm still on the fence about Alma. We have a casting note that says that she's 75, but almost all the other details on it (except Mirabel's age) have been subtly altered.

Comment: Bruno looks 50-ish to me ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The film's writer released a series of tweets about the character's ages;

- **Pedro** - 26 (deceased. Would be 76 if still alive)
- **Alma** - 75*
- **Julieta** - 50 (oldest)
- **Pepa** - 50 (middlest)
- **Bruno** - 50 (youngest)
- **Isabella** - 21
- **Dolores** - 21 (several months younger than Isabella)
- **Luisa** - 19
- **Camilo** - 15
- **Mirabel** - 15 (only slightly younger than Camilo)
- **Antonio** - 5

---

Tweets edited for clarity.

> **Q.** *how old are the triplets in Encanto I cant find them anywhere!!!!*
>
> **Jared Bush:** 50!
>
> <sub><sup>[Per Twitter](https://twitter.com/thejaredbush/status/1475265626717372417)</sup></sub>

and

> **Jared Bush:** *Isabela (21) first grandchild, hence golden child pressure, Dolores (21) couple months younger, in Isa’s shadow hence quieter and Mariano issues, Luisa (19) next, strong middle child and feels need to please. Camilo (15), “theater kid” trying on personas, he’s barely older than Mirabel (15) so when she DIDN’T get a gift after he DID it was shocking & youngest, Antonio (5) with Mirabel in nursery his whole life, hence closeness & first ceremony since Mirabel’s hence nerves. Oh and for those wondering, Félix is a little older than the original triplets and Agustín is a little younger than the triplets. Because Agustín was accident-prone he needed to be healed often… that’s how he and Julieta became a couple.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Per Twitter](https://twitter.com/thejaredbush/status/1468685739969814528)</sup></sub>

and

> **Jared Bush:** *One last Encanto age detail for tonight… and the one that hits me the hardest… When Abuelo Pedro crosses the river, he is the [exact age that
> Sebastian Yatra was… when he recorded Dos Oruguitas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sebasti%C3%A1n_Yatra)… for the scene at… the… river.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Per Twitter](https://twitter.com/thejaredbush/status/1468801430752358402)</sup></sub>

*Note that the age given for Alma 'Abuela' Madrigal is based on an [early article from Disney Insider](https://thedisinsider.com/2020/12/09/exclusive-new-details-for-walt-disney-animation-studios-encanto/) referencing the original casting notes for her character. At that point she was called Andrea.

> Lastly, there is Andrea who is the matriarch of the family. At 75 years old, she is strong and determined, sometimes to a fault. With a dry wit and a tough presence, she doesn’t let anybody get in her way.

Comment: It actually surprised me to learn that Isabella was the oldest of the three sisters, because Luisa calls herself "big sister" during her song.  I guess she either means she's big sister to Mirabel, or she's the strongest.

Comment: "middlest"? I... like it.